# Reversing the Character Case of a string

Tags: c++

I'm stuck on a particular problem. I'm trying to take a string, and reverse the character cases in the string.
For Example: "HaVinG FuN" should flip to "hAvINg fUn." 
I think it has something to do with my loop or my If/Else statements.  What am I missing?  All capitalized characters come out capitalized still.  All lower case characters also come out capitalized as well...  My other two functions are behaving correctly, but not my reverseFunct function...  FYI I've omitted the other functions to try to cut-down on clutter and focus on my problem.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void upperFunct(char *);
void lowerFunct(char *);
void reverseFunct(char *);


int main()
{
cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
char ltrs [300];
cin.getline(ltrs, 300);
char *ptr = nullptr;
ptr = ltrs;

upperFunct(ptr);
lowerFunct(ptr);
reverseFunct(ptr);  

return 0;
 }
//----------------------------------//
void upperFunct(char *ltrptr)
{
int count = 0;
while (ltrptr[count] != '\0')
{
ltrptr[count] = toupper(ltrptr[count]);
count++;
}
{
    cout << "---> toupper function: " << ltrptr << endl;
}
}
//------------------------------------//
void lowerFunct(char *ltrptr)
{ 
int count = 0;
while (ltrptr[count] != '\0')
{
ltrptr[count] = tolower(ltrptr[count]);
count++;
}
cout << "---> tolower function: " << ltrptr << endl;
}
//------------------------------------//
void reverseFunct(char *ltrptr) // <-----NOT REVERSING CHARACTERS 
{
int count = 0;

while (ltrptr[count] != '\0')
{
    if (isupper(ltrptr[count]))
    {
        ltrptr[count] = tolower(ltrptr[count]);
    }
    else
    {
        ltrptr[count] = toupper(ltrptr[count]);
    }
    count++;
}
cout << "---> reverse function: " << ltrptr << endl;
}
```

Comment: You know that this is a one-line program using `std::transform`?

Comment: `else if (islower(ltrptr[count]));` -- See anything wrong with this line?

Comment: [Here is how you write the program](https://www.ideone.com/XGyemX)  where you don't make this mistake:

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To be correct,  the input to `toupper` and `tolower` must be cast to `unsigned char` [sic].

Comment: Cool, I appreciate the help.  This is a bit more advanced more than where I am, hence why it's a more elegant option.  Is there a way to make what I'm doing work, or am I just completely way off with this level of thought that I put into it?  I'm trying to figure out my code mistake vs cheat by using more advanced coding (this is for a class project).  I did not know about the std::transform, haven't gotten there yet in the book :)

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, I removed the semi-colon but it still doesn't give the intended result.

Comment: I've added the rest of my code.  I think the error is when I run my first 2 functions, which somehow makes my last reverse function run in all caps.  When I remove my first 2 functions, my original reverse function works.  What's up with that?

Comment: Correct indentation is for N00bs? Can you easily orient in such a mess?

Comment: It is correct in my IDE, but when I copied and pasted here, this is what happened...  That aside, I am new to programming :).  I am a social worker with a Master's degree that is making a career change, and am in my 1st year at college again :)

Comment: Thanks though user unknown for pointing that out though.  I am a noob, if I wasn't clear above.  I figured my sort of questions I asked, in how simplistic it is, would also make it clear I am a noob.  Otherwise I try to shy-away from using Stack Overflow. I really only come here when I've been stuck for a few days on a problem, and decide I simply just can't seem to figure it out on my own.   I also read such negative comments on Stack Overflow, that I generally come here as a last resort because many people on here are incredibly rude with horrendous social skills, but are programming wizzes.

Answer (score 3):

Your check for lowercase letters reads as

```
else if (islower(ltrptr[count]));
```

Notice the extra semicolon.

This semicolon terminates the if statement, and thus the succeeding conversion to uppercase is not a then-clause to this if statement but rather is executed unconditionally on every character.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, but removing it still doesn't lead to a different result.

Comment: A strange claim as it did on my machine. Please double-check.

Comment: I've added the rest of my code.  I think the error is when I run my first 2 functions, which somehow makes my last reverse function run in all caps.  When I remove my first 2 functions, my original reverse function works.  What's up with that?

Comment: Well, first you convert ALL characters to uppercase, then you convert them ALL to lowercase, then you run the inverse which, taking into account the preceding step, naturally converts them all to uppercase, as it is the only thing inverse can do to all lowercase characters.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, duh! That makes total sense!!!  Thanks for pointing that out!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Change like this

```
// Function Prototypes  "HaVinG FuN" should flip to "hAvINg fUn."
void reverseFunct(char *);

int main()
{
    //cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
    char ltrs[300] = "HaVinG FuN";
    //cin.getline(ltrs, 300);
    char *ptr = nullptr;
    ptr = ltrs;


    reverseFunct(ptr);

    ptr = nullptr;
    return 0;
}

void reverseFunct(char *ltrptr) // <-----NOT REVERSING CHARACTERS 
{
    int count = 0;

    while (ltrptr[count] != '\0')
    {
        if (isupper(ltrptr[count]))
        {
            ltrptr[count] = tolower(ltrptr[count]);
        }
        else 
        {
            ltrptr[count] = toupper(ltrptr[count]);
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout << "---> reverse function: " << ltrptr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're writing C code.  Here's a C++ way to do it:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

char reverse_case_char(char c) {
    const auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); // Sic.
    return ::isupper(uc)? ::tolower(uc): ::toupper(uc);
}
void reverse_case(std::string& str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), reverse_case_char);
}
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
    std::string fun = "HaVinG FuN";
    reverse_case(fun);
    assert(fun == "hAvINg fUn");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fully agree with the use of C++ features. I wouldn't use `std::transform` in this case though. for-each or range based for-loop seems simpler to me. But transform still gets the job done in a much better way than C-style code

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I wrote the code based off of a new learning C++ book, so I thought what I was writing was C++?  I read about the algorithm library and the this type of code, but was leary to use it as I haven't learned about that yet in my book.  Is there not a way to do what I'm trying to do with my current code?

Comment: I've added the rest of my code.  I think the error is when I run my first 2 functions, which somehow makes my last reverse function run in all caps.  When I remove my first 2 functions, my original reverse function works.  What's up with that?

Comment: @Adam: Noting, that you're a beginner, trying to solve a lesson, is an important information which you should leak prominently in your question, since books teach important knowledge with example, you will not use in practice, for didactic purpose. This will not stop some folks suggesting the ready made solution from a library, but it will stop some of them (like me).

Comment: @userunknown - Help is on the way. Kate Gregory is writing an introduction to C++. Or so I've heard. https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: @JiveDadson: Oh, I will definitely watch the rest of the video, after having a first impression. I'm a victim of bad distinction too, I learned C/C++ in the early 90ies, autodidactly, from 2 fat books, which mixed it all together. However, we can inform pupils, that their teacher is doing it wrong, but they won't be allowed to stop doing the homework. And often, the claimed goal of a lesson like flipping upper/lowercase is in reality a lesson about arrays and pointers, to be learnt, and the goal only a legend.

Comment: @userunknown - I learned C in the early 80's, and C++ beginning in 1984. I used to have frequent telephone conversations with Bjarne about where it should go. I attended the first C++ conference in Santa Fe, NM. We were still working out things like what a default copy-constructor should do.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the mistake in your code so no need to repeat that. Instead this answer will give some alternative ways of implementing the task.

Your code is more C-style than C++ style. C++ has a number of functions/features that will allow you to write this in much shorter forms.

```
char ltrs[300] = "HaVinG FuN";
for (auto& ch : ltrs) ch = islower(ch) ? toupper(ch) : tolower(ch);
std::cout << ltrs << std::endl;
```

or

```
char ltrs[300] = "HaVinG FuN";
std::for_each(ltrs, ltrs + strlen(ltrs), [](char& ch) 
             { ch = islower(ch) ? toupper(ch) : tolower(ch); });
std::cout << ltrs << std::endl;
```

or using the std::string

```
std::string str("HaVinG FuN");
for (auto& ch : str) ch = islower(ch) ? toupper(ch) : tolower(ch);
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Using these C++ functions/features makes the program shorter, easier to understand and the risk of bugs is lower.

Comment: @adam `ch` is just a variable name. It could be anything, e.g. just `c`

Comment: Okay, so I think I narrowed down my issues with everyone's help.  All of these suggestions work when I run them, but when I introduce the rest of my functions, the one I wanted to fix breaks.  Let me show everyone to see why they are forcing my reversing function to fail.

Comment: I've added the rest of my code.  I think the error is when I run my first 2 functions, which somehow makes my last reverse function run in all caps.  When I remove my first 2 functions, my original reverse function works.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!!!  I ended up figuring out my answer, while being able to maintain my less-than elegant code that is fitting with my class.  Bipll ended up giving me what I was after, something to think about in terms that my original array was being modified each time.

I realize that my solution is sloppy and not appropriate for a work environment, but it is in-line with my homework assignment, as our teacher is encouraging us to learn C++ from the ground-up, not getting too much direct answers from places like SO.  So I'm glad I learned a bit from here, as well as an indirect way to help me see my issues.

I ended up making a copy of my original array, and just passing that copy to my last reversing function.  I was able to use the original array for the first 2 functions because the 1st function capitalized each character in the array, while the 2nd made them all lowercase.  The 3rd function, the reverse, therefore had to have access to the original array, but in the 3rd order.  The easiest way for a noob like me, given where I am in the class, was to make a copy of the 1st array and use that for the 3rd function.

```
//Snippet of code I needed
int main()
{
int index = 0;
cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
const int Size = 300;
char ltrs[Size];
cin.getline(ltrs, Size);
char arrayCopy[Size];
char *ptr = nullptr;
char *ptr2 = nullptr;
ptr = ltrs;

//Copy of ltrs Array
//----------------------------------//
while (ptr[index] != '\0')          //
{                                   //
    arrayCopy[index] = ptr[index];  //
    index++;                        //
}                                   //
    arrayCopy[index] = '\0';        //
                                    //
    ptr2 = arrayCopy;               //
//----------------------------------//
return 0;
}
// Function to Reverse
void reverseFunct(char *ltrptr) 
{
int count = 0;

while (ltrptr[count] != '\0')
  {
    if (isupper(ltrptr[count]))
    {
        ltrptr[count] = tolower(ltrptr[count]);
    }
    else
    {
        ltrptr[count] = toupper(ltrptr[count]);
    }
    count++;
  }
cout << "---> reverse function: " << ltrptr << endl;
}
```